# Using bib files in Latex - path definition?

Tags: bibtex, miktex

I am relatively new to latex and I am puzzled by the way citations work. I used Mendeley to generate a bib-file with all my references in it but I am having trouble using citations in my text.

What I do is this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\bibliography{C:/Users/PC/Documents/biblio}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
Please insert a citation here \cite{Ross2010}

\end{document}
```

I use MikTex and typeset with pdfLaTex+MakeIndex+BibTex and I used Mendeley to create a large .bib file with all my references in for me to reference in the beginning of the document but when I check, it doesn't recognize any of the references in the list and just write "?" in the pdf.

What am I missing?

Comment: Plesae have a look at https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Creating_a_Bibliography

Answer (score 1):

A corrected example would be the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
Please insert a citation here \cite{<key>}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{<filename>}

\end{document}
```

Where you need to replace  and  by the corresponding values. Please note the following changes I made: `\bibliography` has to be inside your document (not in the preamble) where you want your list of references to appear. Additionally, you need a `\bibliographystyle` command to tell the compiler what style your bibliography should have. There are severaly styles available from which you can choose. (For more styles there are also packages like `natbib` which might come in handy).

Customizing a `bibtex` style is also possible, but I personally would recommend to use `biblatex` instead, as it is easier to customie and more flexible. A MWE for `biblatex` would look like the following:

This example must be compiled using latex, biber, latex, latex.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{<filename.bib>}

\begin{document}
\cite{<key>}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

For a more in depth explanation, please have a look at thie excellent answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25702/134144

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot the following package for biblatex:

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
```

Try it and update me!